# Solution for get output of tree ( String ), generated by AST in C

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

Please nyone can help me?

```c
struct TREE {
    int operation;
    struct TREE *left;
    struct TREE *right;
    char *value;
};

struct TREE *make_node(int operation, struct TREE *left, struct TREE *right, char *value) {
    struct TREE *n;
    
    n = (struct TREE *)malloc(sizeof(struct TREE));
    if(n == NULL) { printf("Unable to Malloc\n"); exit(1); }
    
    n -> operation = operation;
    n -> left = left;
    n -> right = right;
    n -> value = value;
    
    return n;
}
```

I create a parser and tree for my program. And this is how it works.

First, input (e.g.) `2 + 3 * 4` to the program. The programm will parse it according to the *BODMAS* theory and generate Tree. **Each values as stored as a String. Not an Integer**.
According to the Example I mentioned, the generated tree is `2 + ( 3 * 4 )`.

```
      +
     / \
    /   \
   *     2
  / \
 /   \
3     4
```

Now I want to write **Recursive** function to print this tree. I tried this method.

```c
int print_tree(struct TREE *n) {
    char *left_val, right_val;
    
    if(n -> left) {
        left_val = n -> left -> value;
        print_tree(n -> left);
    }
    
    if(n -> right) {
        right_val = n -> right -> value;
        print_tree(n -> right);
    }
    
    switch(n -> operation) {
        case '+':
            printf("%s %d %s\n", left_val, n -> operation, right_val);
            break;
        
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to get the output as follows. Print left and right part of one section, According to my example section means `3 + 4` But this does not work :/
please anyone can slove my problem?

Comment: Use a debugger. It'll probably show you that `n` is NULL. Your `print_tree` recursive function needs to handle the termination case - which is when `n` is `NULL`.

Comment: You should create a [mre]. I suggest to add a `main` function that constructs a sample tree and calls `print_tree` in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn you about `left_value = print_tree(n -> left);`? `print_tree` has no return value; there is nothing to assign to `left_value` so it has no meaningful value after that statement.